# how to start a thread for a period of time

Tags: c#, threadpool

I have created the thread class and started that thread.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Thread_class
{
    class Program
    {
        class SubThread
        {
            public void PrintValue()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inside PrintValue() of SubThread Class " + i);
                    Thread.Sleep(5);
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SubThread subthread=new SubThread();
            Thread thread = new Thread( new ThreadStart( subthread.PrintValue));
            thread.Start();
             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inside Main Class " + i);
                    Thread.Sleep(1);

                }
            thread.Join();
        }

    }
}
```

How can I execute the above method for every specified period  of time? Is it possible to use threading. The timer method to set the time period for to start the thread?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a `Threading.Timer`.

```
int timeToStart = 2000;
int period = 1000;

SubThread sub = new SubThread();
Timer timer = new Timer(o => sub.PrintValue(), null, timeToStart, period);
```

The timer will wait for 1 second, and then run your task every 2 seconds.

You don't need to create your own threads for this, the timer will spawn a thread if necessary.
Don't forget to call `Dispose` when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `System.Threading.Timer`, also note that `System.Threading.Timer` calls callback method each time in the thread from ThreadPool, so you don't even need to create Thread, just run the timer, and the callback will run in the different thread.

Just call

```
Timer t = new Timer(TimerProc, null, startAfter, period);

private void TimerProc(object state)
{
   // This operation will run in the thread from threadpool
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Thread_class
{
   class Program
   {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SubThread subthread = new SubThread();
        Thread thread = new Thread(subthread.PrintValue);
        thread.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Main Class " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(1);

        }
        thread.Join();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
class SubThread
{
    public void PrintValue()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside PrintValue() of SubThread Class " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you.